# Problems with input check in c++

Tags: c++, input

I want the program to loop until the input is valid (x is an int, and x>0), but my program accepts the input when I give it 1,1 and loops infinitely when I give a string to it, repeating "Wrong input!".

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool fail;
    int x;
    do{
        cin >> x;
        fail=(cin.fail() || x<=0);
        if (fail){
            cout << "Wrong input!" <<endl;
            cin.clear();
        };
    }while(fail);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use standard member function `ignore` in the if statement. For example

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),’\n’);
```

or just

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

It is used to skip invalid symbols in the buffer.

Comment: Shall I use it instead of cin.clear()?

Comment: @R2DToo Insert the call before cin.clear()

Comment: Still keeps looping forever for the input "asd" ..
And for "1.1" it gives back 1

Comment: @R2DToo I am sorry. Place the call of ignore AFTER the call of clear.

Comment: @R2DToo ignore without arguments skips only one symbol from the buffer. Use the first form of the call if you want to ignore all the buffer with invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

You may read an entire line and convert the line with a string stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    bool fail;
    int x;
    do{
        std::string line;
        fail = ! getline(std::cin, line);
        if( ! fail) {
            std::istringstream s(line);
            fail = ! (s >> x) 
                || x < 0  
                || ! s.eof(); // The entire line represents an integer
        }
        if(fail) {
            std::cout << "Wrong input!" << std::endl;
        };
    } while(fail);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works! Thanks!